# Programming language selection for showing image with other images on

Tags: image

I want to make a program that displays an image with other images on it (a map with various icons on it). What language (and library!) would you recommend, based on these facts:

-I have some basic oop knowledge
-I'll need a free and windows OS IDE for that

I would guess java? But it is not easy to compress my question to a good quality google search string....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> displays an image with other images on it

Almost every language can achieve this. Such as Python with [`Pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) C++ with [`opencv`](https://opencv.org/) and  many other options. (I believe most of mainstream languages will have their own image library)

The problem is, what you want to implement specifically?

if you just want to put some images on to another image, and you do not need extra interactive function. Go with Python and Pillow, it is easy to learn and can perfectly solve your problems.